# Difference between "bundle install --deployment" and "bundle install --path vendor/bundle"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

What exactly is the difference between `bundle install --deployment` and `bundle install --path vendor/bundle`?

I've read the link below which explains what deployment mode does, but I'm still not sure, because both of these commands install the gems to the path `vendor/bundle`.
My vague understanding is that `--deployment` sets the `Gemfile.lock` into place, so that it can't be updated anymore. But please correct me if I'm wrong.

https://bundler.io/man/bundle-install.1.html#DEPLOYMENT-MODE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, `bundle install --deployment` doesn't even look at your `Gemfile` and will just install all dependencies from your `Gemfile.lock` (and will fail if your `Gemfile.lock` has dependency issues). `bundle install --path` does a regular `bundle install` with a specific target folder (which, in your example, is coincidentally the same as the target folder for `bundle install --deployment`). The main difference in your example is that `bundle install` will try to change your `Gemfile.lock` if your `Gemfile` has changed.

The reason that Bundler installs to `vendor/bundle` in deployment mode is that a regular `bundle install` will install gems to a shared folder every project uses. It's preferrable to isolate your dependencies between projects and deployments.

Comment: Thank you so much!